# I get Error of "TypeError: handleDeleteNode is not a Function" in reactJs project ,I am passing function as props from app.js to folder.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-props

I am providing code of App.js and i am passing props from app.js to Folder.js but when i am receiving props in folder.js and call function handleDeleteNode then it gives me error in console that "handleDeleteNode is not function".

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import explorer from "./Data/FolderData";
import Folder from "./Components/Folder";
import Usetraversetree from "./Hooks/Use-traverse-tree";

function App() {
  const [ExplorerData, setExplorerData] = useState(explorer);

  const { insertNode, deleteNode } = Usetraversetree();

  const handleInsertNode = (folderId, item, isFolder) => {
    const finalTree = insertNode(ExplorerData, folderId, item, isFolder);
    setExplorerData(finalTree);
  };

  const handleDeleteNode = (folderId) => {
    const DeleteTree = deleteNode(ExplorerData, folderId);
    setExplorerData(DeleteTree);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Folder
        handleDeleteNode={handleDeleteNode}
        ExplorerData={ExplorerData}
        handleInsertNode={handleInsertNode}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code of Folder.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Usetraversetree from "../Hooks/Use-traverse-tree";

const Folder = ({ handleDeleteNode, ExplorerData, handleInsertNode }) => {
  const { updateNode } = Usetraversetree();
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState({
    visible: false,
    isFolder: false,
  });
  const [showInputEdit, setShowInputEdit] = useState({
    visible: false,
  });

  const handleNewFolder = (e, isFolder) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setExpand(true);
    setShowInput({
      visible: true,
      isFolder,
    });
  };

  const handleEditFolder = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setExpand(true);
    setShowInputEdit({
      visible: true,
    });
  };

  const onAddFolder = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.value) {
      handleInsertNode(ExplorerData.id, e.target.value, showInput.isFolder);
      setShowInput({ ...showInput, visible: false });
    }
  };

  const onEditFolder = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.target.value) {
      updateNode(ExplorerData, ExplorerData.id, e.target.value);
      setShowInputEdit({ ...showInputEdit, visible: false });
    }
  };

  const OnDelete = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    handleDeleteNode(ExplorerData.id);
  };

  if (ExplorerData.isFolder) {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>
        <div className="folder" onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}>
          <span>{ExplorerData.name}</span>
          <div>
            <button onClick={(e) => handleNewFolder(e, true)}>Folder+</button>
            <button onClick={(e) => handleNewFolder(e, false)}>File+</button>
            <button onClick={(e) => handleEditFolder(e)}>Edit</button>
            {ExplorerData.name === "root" ? (
              ""
            ) : (
              <button onClick={OnDelete}>Delete</button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: expand ? "block" : "none", paddingLeft: 25 }}>
          {showInput.visible && (
            <div className="inputContainer">
              <span>{showInput.isFolder ? "" : ""}</span>
              <input
                type={"text"}
                onBlur={() => setShowInput({ ...showInput, visible: false })}
                className="inputContainer_input"
                autoFocus
                onKeyDown={onAddFolder}
              />
            </div>
          )}
          {showInputEdit.visible && (
            <div className="inputContainer">
              <input
                type={"text"}
                onBlur={() =>
                  setShowInputEdit({ ...showInputEdit, visible: false })
                }
                className="inputContainer_input"
                autoFocus
                onKeyDown={onEditFolder}
                defaultValue={ExplorerData.name}
                onChange={(e) => e.target.value}
              />
            </div>
          )}

          {ExplorerData.item.map((exp) => {
            return (
              <Folder
                handleInsertNode={handleInsertNode}
                ExplorerData={exp}
                key={exp.id}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="folder">
          <span className="file">{ExplorerData.name}</span>
          <div>
            <button onClick={(e) => handleEditFolder(e)}>Edit</button>
            <button onClick={OnDelete}>Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: expand ? "block" : "none", paddingLeft: 25 }}>
          {showInputEdit.visible && (
            <div className="inputContainer">
              <input
                type={"text"}
                onBlur={() =>
                  setShowInputEdit({ ...showInputEdit, visible: false })
                }
                className="inputContainer_input"
                autoFocus
                onKeyDown={onEditFolder}
                defaultValue={ExplorerData.name}
                onChange={(e) => e.target.value}
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
};

export default Folder;
```

code of useTraverseTree.js

```
      const Usetraversetree = () => {
  const insertNode = function (tree, folderId, item, isFolder) {
    if (tree.id === folderId && tree.isFolder) {
      tree.item.unshift({
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        name: item,
        isFolder: isFolder,
        item: [],
      });
      return tree;
    }

    let latestNode = [];
    latestNode = tree.item.map((ob) => {
      return insertNode(ob, folderId, item, isFolder);
    });

    return { ...tree, item: latestNode };
  };
  //
  //
  const updateNode = function (tree, fileId, editValue) {
    if (tree.id === fileId) {
      tree.name = editValue;
      return tree;
    }
    let latestNode = [];
    latestNode = tree.item.map((ob) => {
      return updateNode(ob, fileId, editValue);
    });

    return { ...tree, item: latestNode };
  };
  //
  //
  const deleteNode = function (tree, fileId) {
    for (let i = 0; i < tree.item.length; i++) {
      if (tree.item[i].id === fileId) {
        tree.item.splice(i, 1);
        return tree;
      }
    }
    let latestNode = [];
    latestNode = tree.item.map((ob) => {
      return deleteNode(ob, fileId);
    });

    return { ...tree, item: latestNode };
  };

  return { insertNode, deleteNode, updateNode };
};

export default Usetraversetree;
```

code of explorer

```
const explorer = {
  id: "1",
  name: "root",
  isFolder: true,
  item: [
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "public",
      isFolder: true,
      item: [
        {
          id: "3",
          name: "public nested 1",
          isFolder: true,
          item: [
            {
              id: "4",
              name: "index.html",
              isFolder: false,
              item: [],
            },
            {
              id: "5",
              name: "hello.html",
              isFolder: false,
              item: [],
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: "6",
          name: "public_nested_file",
          isFolder: false,
          item: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "7",
      name: "src",
      isFolder: true,
      item: [
        {
          id: "8",
          name: "App.js",
          isFolder: false,
          item: [],
        },
        {
          id: "9",
          name: "Index.js",
          isFolder: false,
          item: [],
        },
        {
          id: "10",
          name: "style.css",
          isFolder: false,
          item: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "11",
      name: "package.json",
      isFolder: false,
      item: [],
    },
  ],
};

export default explorer;
```

I am Passing Props from App.js to Folder.js But I get Error which is "handleDeleteNode is not a Function".
So How to solve this Problem ?

Comment: In `Folder.js`, you didn't pass `handleDeleteNode` to your `<Folder />`

Comment: thanks for help ....i just ignore that ....,